# onclick javascript function inserting value in input tag is not working on windows 8 in internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, html

when i am inserting the value into the input tag by onclick function in javascript, but the value is not inserting in input tag when i am using internet explorer 10 on windows 8,  but the values are inserting in input tag when i am using google chrome.

This is my html code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body
<ul id="nav" style="font-size:75%">
    <li><a href="#">BIHAR</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="BGSRU01" onclick="bgsru()">BGSRU01</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="input_text">
<input type="text" id="input_text2">    

</body>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function bgsru(){
alert(1)
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#input_text").val("BIHAR");
    $("#input_text2").val("BGSRU01");
}
</script>
```

i have enabled the javascript in internet explorer 10, onlick function is working alert() function pop is coming, but the values are not inserting.
please suggest how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `event` inside your code. In IE the global object might not be there so

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Will be probably throwing error and js execution will stop at that point.

try modifying the code as follows:

```
<li><a href="#" id="BGSRU01" onclick="bgsru(event)">BGSRU01</a></li>
```

and

```
function bgsru(event){
  event = event || window.event;
  (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
  alert(1)
  $("#input_text").val("BIHAR");
  $("#input_text2").val("BGSRU01");
}
```

Comment: No, its not working!!.. . please share any other code.

Comment: if i din't put event.preventDefault() in the url its showing # at the end.

Comment: @John try the updated code… too bad i can't test in IE right now :/

Comment: yes, i tried i got its working. but the '#' is showing in the URL like   this : http://localhost/vi/index_test.php#

Comment: please suggest, how to remove anchor tag '#' in  URL, when i am using menus and submenus

Comment: @John does the updated code help..? if not you'll have to wait few hours until i get my windows machine :/

Comment: Nope!! its not working please share another code , until i will wait.

Comment: @John i'm not sure why IE is displaying the `#`, but if you really want to remove it, change `<a>`'s `href` to `<a href="javascript: void(0)">BIHAR</a>`